# don't allow program to kill any not realted processes

Tags: linux, unix, fork, system-calls, kill

I'm currently learning how to use system calls such as fork, exec*, and kill. I had a task that required to send SIGKILL to all parent's sibilngs created with fork if one of fork calls failed. So I did smth like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfchilds; i++) {
  childs[i] = fork();
  if (childs[i] == -1)
    killAll(childs, i);
...

void killAll(pid_t childs, size_t numOfChilds) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfChilds; i++)
    kill(childs[i], SIGKILL);
}
```

But I messed up and accidentally send `kill(-1, SIGKILL)` and killed all processe that I could. Fortunately I didn't lose any unsave data, but `kill -9 -1` is not the best practice to logout.

So. Is there any way I can restrict my program killing any processes that don't belong to it, so it could only kill one it created with fork?

Comment: Run your program under a different user, so it can only kill processes that belong to this user.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try it

Comment: General hints: 1. `SIGKILL` should only be used as the last resort if you cannot stop the process by other means. If there is no nicer way, I suggest to send `SIGTERM` first and give the processes some time to terminate. If this doesn't work you can send SIGKILL later. 2. The argument type `pid_t childs` of function `killAll` is wrong when you want to pass an array. You shoule enable all compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: Dear, @Bodo, thanks for your reply. 1) yeah I know that it's bad to send -9, but it was a part of the task. 2) It's just a typo, I didn't copy the code.

Would be nice if you actually suggested a solution, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Demiler The solution to use a different user was already proposed in [mbaitoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411928/mbaitoff)'s comment. I think there is no easier way to prevent your program from killing too many processes in case of program errors. (You could also run your possibly buggy program in a container or in a VM.)

Comment: @Bodo, yep, I guess so